# Spark for Json Data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am processing a  nested complex Json and below is the schema for it.

```
root
 |-- businessEntity: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- payGroup: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- reportingPeriod: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- worker: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tax: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- qtdAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ytdAmount: double (nullable =
```

My requirement is to create a hashmap with code concatenated with qtdAmount as key and value of qtdAmount as value.
Map.put(code + "qtdAmount" , qtdAmount). How can i do this with spark.

I tried with below shell commands.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
val cdm = sqlcontext.read.json("/user/edureka/CDM/cdm.json")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SQL").config("spark.some.config.option","some-vale").getOrCreate()
cdm.createOrReplaceTempView("CDM")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT businessEntity[0].payGroup[0] from CDM").show()
val address = spark.sql("SELECT businessEntity[0].payGroup[0].reportingPeriod.worker[0].person.address from CDM as address")
val worker = spark.sql("SELECT businessEntity[0].payGroup[0].reportingPeriod.worker from CDM")
val tax = spark.sql("SELECT businessEntity[0].payGroup[0].reportingPeriod.worker[0].tax from CDM")
val tax = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT businessEntity[0].payGroup[0].reportingPeriod.worker[0].tax from CDM")
tax.select("tax.code")


val codes = tax.select(expode(tax("code"))
scala> val codes = tax.withColumn("code",explode(tax("tax.code"))).withColumn("qtdAmount",explode(tax("tax.qtdAmount"))).withColumn("ytdAmount",explode(tax("tax.ytdAmount")))
```

i am trying to get all the codes and qtdAmount into a map. But i am not getting it. Using multiple explode statements for a single DF, is producing cartesian product of the elements.

Could someone please help on how to parse the json of this much complex in spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `code` and `qtyAmount` in this way.

```
import sqlcontext.implicits._

     cdm.select(
        $"businessEntity.element.payGroup.element.reportingPeriod.worker.element.tax.element.code".as("code"),
        $"businessEntity.element.payGroup.element.reportingPeriod.worker.element.tax.element.qtdAmount".as("qtdAmount")
      ).show
```

For detailed information, check [this](http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/)